# Prevent Web Login with Credentials Exposed

Tags: credentials

We have a situation here. The client which I work for is currently placed as a finance brokerage firm and their current positioning are:

1. The firm has different branches in different locations
2. The firm has a giant customerbase
3. The firm takes security serious

Now, their requirements specifies these:

1. Passwords if shared by customers should trigger an OTP to real account
2. With generation of OTP, the account owner is informed

The question is what can be done to prevent different people using the same shared password or in simple, what are different ways in which the firm can restrict the use of shared password for intended users apart from using OTP?

Note: Earlier they had trading password which alongside with the main password could be shared to the third-party so that's not a reliable option.

Comment: Is OTP in this context suppose to mean One Time Pad?

Comment: @John, it's one time password which means on every access attempt - one has to receive random generated code at his/her registered device to the firm.

Comment: I would think you could associate the OTP to a specific user in the database, so it is just valid for that one person.

Comment: @John - OTP will itself take care. Could you kindly re-read the question? It says what are other measures that can be taken besides OTP?

Comment: While I prefer OTP, what about TFA or several secret questions? I do not mean the stuff we all can get on social media websites. Why are you looking for an alternative for OTP?

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I don't really understand the question. Is the password sharing an option of the application, so that another person may have temporary access (or once)? How is the sharing supposed to take place? Shouldn't the account owner be the one who authorizes the shared access?
Sorry if these questions are stupid, but I am not entirely sure how this system should work. This might as well be the same for others as nobody else has answered your question yet.

Comment: @Jeroen: it's required as for now in the firm since we have been asked for making a solution which can make this possible without having to deploy OTP solutions for it. 

John: password sharing isn't an option. As the OP says, we have a policy of trading secret key which is combined with the master password for any web login to work but here the risks are if one customer shares both his/her secret trading password and teh master password, there is nothing that can stop it.

And hence the security team wants to find an alternative way but without having to use OTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with a password is, that it can be shared and there is no good way of realizing if it was shared. You do not know easily if person A or person B used the password. As @Rory mentioned there are ways to try to cope with that. Implementing a sophisticated logic to verify if the password is used by the same human.
You can track the client's IP and if a user will try to login from south Africa one hour after being logged in from Australia your logic might deem this suspicious.

You should use something that can not be shared easily.

It is easier to identify the person with a second factor. You can use an OTP token that generates a One Time Password and which the user needs to enter and or you could send an OTP to the mobile phone of the user. Both scenarios are supported by [privacyIDEA](http://privacyidea.org) which is an open source solution you might take a look at.

But still the problem with OTP is, that person A could also share the current OTP with person B even via phone or email. Person B: "Hey, person A, I know your static password, but what is your current OTP?"

If you want to be really safe, you might want to use client certificates preferrable on a smartcard. Then the user needs to present his smartcard to login. person A will not be able to "share" his smartcard via phone ;-)

Comment: Which means hardware security via RSA tokens could be a go, right? I see no standard solution to this via web security implementations.

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick Google Authenticator could also be used as the 2nd factor.

Comment: @ShirtamBhowmick You could use RSA. But RSA uses a unknown proprietary algorithm. It uses preseeded tokens, where you are not sure, where copies of the seeds are located... I would not use RSA ;-)

Comment: @cornelinux could you recommend a very good alternative?

Comment: @ShritamBhowmick If you are thinking of OTP tokens do not use RSA SecurID but rather use Yubikeys in conjunction with privacyIDEA. If you want to use client certificates on smartcards, you need to check the users operating systems, since you will need to enroll SC drivers.

Comment: @cornelinux yes this makes sense. As of now we are rolling out the same. This approach can be great in implementation as well (considering others were not well-fit for business use cases).

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the question correctly you're looking to stop users sharing passwords on a web based system.

A common approach for this is to limit each account to one simultaneous session, and the if a new session is commenced, to terminate the original one.

This reduces the effectiveness of sharing passwords as they can't actually use the system at the same time.

You could also try to detect abuse by noting whether one account was coming from a number of different systems ( e.g. Checking things like user agent or source ip address) and then taking some kind of actions if abuse is detected.

Comment: @Rory, thanks for the heads up but the risk is if the original user isn't logged in and after logging out the sessions are destroyed at the server side - In anyway the ones who are not intended users could re-create new session tokens when they login with the master password and trading password.